# Why is Set.contains() much faster for Point than for List<Integer> of size 2?

Tags: java, performance, set, lookup, timing

I recently needed to do many-many lookups on a set of integer pairs for solving a problem in a programming contest. I program in Java. Normally I would use arrays for pairs of integers, but because sets in Java do not work with arrays, I decided to use lists this time. I later discovered that my solution was slow, but another contestant's solution using [`Point`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html) instead was much faster.

I implemented a small benchmark to compare the two. I discovered that `Set.contains()` on a `Set<List<Integer>>` (where each `List<Integer>` is of size 2) is on average about 4.5 times slower than on a `Set<Point>`, regardless of whether the pair is actually contained in the set. I thought the reason could stem from different implementations of `hashCode()` and additionally implemented a custom `Point` class that uses `List.hashCode()`. This appears to be part of the reason, but the difference with an actual `List<Integer>` is still considerable.

This is my benchmark code:

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

public class IntPairTiming {

    public static final int SIZE = 1_000_000;
    public static final int TRIES = 100_000_000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Random random = new Random();

        // Pairs to store
        Set<Point> pointSet = new HashSet<>();
        Set<List<Integer>> listSet = new HashSet<>();
        Set<MyPoint> myPointSet = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            Point point = new Point(random.nextInt(), random.nextInt());
            pointSet.add(point);
            List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(point.x, point.y);
            listSet.add(list);
            myPointSet.add(new MyPoint(point.x, point.y, list));
        }

        // Pair to lookup
        Point point = new Point(random.nextInt(), random.nextInt());
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(point.x, point.y);
        MyPoint myPoint = new MyPoint(point.x, point.y, list);
        pointSet.add(point);
        listSet.add(list);
        myPointSet.add(myPoint);

        // Time set of points
        timeLookup(pointSet, point, "Set of Points");

        // Time set of lists
        timeLookup(listSet, list, "Set of Lists");

        // Time set of mypoints
        timeLookup(myPointSet, myPoint, "Set of MyPoints");
    }

    private static <T> void timeLookup(Set<T> set, T obj, String what) {
        System.out.println("-----------");
        System.out.printf("%s:%n", what);
        System.out.printf("Contains = %s%n", set.contains(obj));
        long s = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < TRIES; i++) set.contains(obj);
        long e = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.printf("Average lookup = %sns%n", (e - s) / TRIES);
    }

    private static class MyPoint extends Point {

        private final List<Integer> list;

        public MyPoint(int x, int y, List<Integer> list) {
            super(x, y);
            this.list = list;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return this.list.hashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
-----------
Set of Points:
Contains = true
Average lookup = 12ns
-----------
Set of Lists:
Contains = true
Average lookup = 55ns
-----------
Set of MyPoints:
Contains = true
Average lookup = 25ns
```

Why is there such a noticeable difference? From my understanding, both `hashCode()` and `equals()` should perform more or less equivalently on a `Point` and a `List<Integer>` of size 2. What if we need to lookup tuples of more than two elements, would a custom class similar to `Point` always be more efficient than a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is based on the fact that the [expense for `equals()` on any sort of `AbstractList`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractList.java#AbstractList.equals%28java.lang.Object%29) is greater than one would imagine.

The implementation needs to construct an iterator, iterate it, and compare all elements (and `hashCode` would need to as well), while a dedicated `Point` class has two comparisons that are extremely easily optimized by the JIT (due to field offsets not changing as much) while a list requires much more indirection.

At a point (no pun intended) where your fields number into the tens it becomes a premature optimization to create a separate tuple class unless that tuple class itself has some use as a POJO in itself.

Answer (score 1):

`Point` contains primitive fields, whereas `List<Integer>` contains objects, although very simple.

The hash code calculation for `Point` will use these fields directly, while the hash code calculation for `List<Integer>` will, loosely speaking, require two more deference operations to get to the actual values.